# Generators of $\Gamma_{1}(6)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Is it right, that \begin{align}
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}5&-1\\6&-1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}7&-3\\12&-5\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
\end{align} is a set of generators for the group $\Gamma_{1}(6)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_1(6) \subset \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$. In this case, you should note that
$ \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -1 \\ 6 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not actually in $\Gamma_1(6)$, as neither $5$ nor $-1$ is congruent to $1 \bmod 6$.

So no, that is not a set of generators.